# After deleting a line from a text file all null characters disappear (UNIX)

Tags: linux, unix, sed, command

I have a file with lines containing the null character. I want to delete one of the lines as follows:

```
sed "2d" file.txt> file.tmp
```

The problem is that in the resulting file all null disappear, as shown below:

[image: image of the screen capture]

What could be the reason?

Comment: What do you mean by null character?

Comment: Character '\000': http://i.stack.imgur.com/MEMHb.png

Comment: The snippet shown in section 'AFTER'. Is that what you want or is that what you are getting now? What is the actual expected output?

Comment: Okay, someone coded sed incorrectly. Not sure what else you want said.

Comment: It is the result I get. I need to keep null characters. The problem is that in addition to delete the line, changes the rest of the file. I just want to remove the line without impacting rest of the file.

Comment: That works well for me... (OSX 10.11)

Comment: No idea... I lose the nulls (Linux Redhat)